# list virtual folders in azure blob storage via python API

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I was reading [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/) but I cannot find a way to list all the (virtual) folder under a container without getting all the files. I have 26K files in 500 (virtual) folders. I just want to get the list of folder without having to wait few minutes to get the output of `list_blobs` containing the entire file list. Is there a way to do that? or at least tell `list_blobs` to not go deeper than `n` levels below a container?

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps it's not too late for someone. `list_blobs` doesn't accept a `delimiter` argument. Instead, use `walk_blobs` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-walk-blobs)) to get a generator with the files. Using `delimiter="/"` you will get the next sublevel of files/folders:

For example:

```py
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(file_connect_str)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
for file in container_client.walk_blobs('my_folder/', delimiter='/'):
    print(file.name)
```

will return:

```
"my_folder/sub_folder_1/"
"my_folder/sub_folder_2/"
```

Comment: I like this example using walk blobs, because I can use the prefix to list folder inside other folders.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want to get the top-level files from the container you can use  an empty string: `walk_blobs(name_starts_with="", delimiter='/')`. As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata), the delimiter can be any character as it uses a flat storage-based scheme (define your own delimiter)

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like the following:

```
from azure.storage import BlobService

blob_service = BlobService(account_name='account-name', account_key='account-key')

bloblistingresult = blob_service.list_blobs(container_name='container-name', delimiter='/') 
for i in bloblistingresult.prefixes:
        print(i.name) #this will print the names of the virtual folders
```

[SDK Source Code Reference: BlobService.list_blobs()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L1159)
[SKD Source Code Reference: BlobService.list_blobs().prefixes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/bc985392407459717634b46eda7d8f66b7ffb4dc/azure/storage/blob/models.py#L251)

Comment: Thank you this basically got me close.... However, I don't see the .PREFIX method from bloblistingresult.   I have .ITEMS and .NEXT_MARKER.   I did do ```for each_item in bloblistingresult: print(bloblistingresult.name)``` which prints out the top level directory folders but doesn't go past the top level... For example if there are subfolders I dont see them.

Answer (score 1):

@ Gaurav Mantri pointed out the correct way to get a list of BlobPrefix elements, and we can leverage this to create a function to require your requirement:

For example I have 4 levels in directory:

```
import azure
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
blob_service = BlobService(account_name='<account_name>', account_key='<account_key>')
def getfolders(depth=1):
    result = []
    searched = []
    delimiter = '/'
    print depth
    blob_list = blob_service.list_blobs('container-name',delimiter='/')
    result.extend(str(l.name) for l in blob_list.prefixes)
    #for l in blob_list.prefixes:
    #    result.extend(str(l.name))
    depth -= 1 
    while (depth>0):
        print 'result: \n'
        print ','.join(str(p) for p in result)
        print 'searched: \n'
        print ','.join(p for p in searched)
        for p in [item for item in result if item not in searched]:
            print p +' in '+ str(depth)
            searched.append(p)
            blob_list = blob_service.list_blobs('vsdeploy',prefix=p,delimiter='/')
            result.extend(str(l.name) for l in blob_list.prefixes)
        depth -= 1 
    return result

blob_list = getfolders(4)
print ','.join(str(p) for p in blob_list)
```