# How to get full paths of all files in a container in azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

How do I get a list of every single directory under an azure container using python?  I can’t seem to find documentation on how to do this and at same time I’m new to azure and its terminology so that probably doesn’t help either.

For example I may have a container named *sales_data” and underneath it I may have:

- product1 / usa
- product1/ international 
  — sales_reps/data
- stores/ 50_different_subfolders_here
- new_folders_created_all_the_time_here/new_sub_folders_here

I’d like a list that laid out the full path of each of directory. 
Where do I go from here?

```
blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name = my_account_name, token_credential=my_azure_creds)
```

I've figured out how to get the listing of all files in a terminal directory such as what is below, but again I can't find the pathing instructions...

```
prefix_objects = blobService.list_blobs('sales_data', prefix='/product1/usa/')
for each_file in prefix_objects:
     print(each_file.name)
```

Comment: Besides, could you please tell me your Azure storage SDK version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list virtual folders in azure blob storage via python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477687/list-virtual-folders-in-azure-blob-storage-via-python-api)

Comment: @runningbirds did my answer resolve your question?

Comment: did you find a way to do this in python v12? I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 3):

Here's a full example (for version *12.0.0* of the SDK) which will find the full path of all files under a certain container.

To run the following code, you will need to retrieve the connection string for the storage account you are interested in.

---

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def ls_files(client, path, recursive=False):
    '''
    List files under a path, optionally recursively
    '''
    if not path == '' and not path.endswith('/'):
      path += '/'

    blob_iter = client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=path)
    files = []
    for blob in blob_iter:
      relative_path = os.path.relpath(blob.name, path)
      if recursive or not '/' in relative_path:
        files.append(relative_path)
    return files

# Connection string for the storage account.
connection_string = ''

# Name of the container you are interested in.
container_name = 'sales_data'

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

files = ls_files(client, '', recursive=True)
```

---

**Note**: The function *ls_files* comes from [this repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_directory_interface.py#L107).

All credits for that source code go to the author, rakshith91.